# Kubeflow pipeline error "module 'kfp.dsl' has no attribute 'RUN_ID_PLACEHOLDER'"

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am running this Kubeflow pipeline example below in Jupyter NB. In the def gh_summ() part, it gave me an error message: "module 'kfp.dsl' has no attribute 'RUN_ID_PLACEHOLDER'". Any suggestions? Thank you!

The Kubeflow pipeline Jupyter nb:

Need to download it first `

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/examples/master/github_issue_summarization/pipelines/example_pipelines/pipelines-notebook.ipynb`
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a really old SDK package installed.
Try to run
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade kfp --user`